# Cannot scrape Google news BY DATE in R using R package 'tm.plugin.webmining'

Tags: r, time-series, tm

I'm using x64 windows
I would like to scrape google news data and I want a time series from 2004-2016 of news articles(headlines) per month or day, in order to conduct some analysis. 
I tried some sources in R that is GoogleNewsSource(), getURIAsynchronous, read_html() ...
 first,

```
library("tm")
library("tm.plugin.webmining")
googlenews <- GoogleNewsSource("yen", since="1-2-2015", until="31-2-2015")
```

(Someone answered about similar to this problem, add a option *as_drrb=b*.
 But not work)

Second,

```
url <- "https://www.google.co.kr/search?q=yen&num=100&hl=en&tbm=nws&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:4/20/2014,cd_max:1/14/2015"
uris = c(url)
txt = getURIAsynchronous(uris)</i>
```

When I run this code, news are newest like 'Dec 9, 2016' NOT 2015.
In the results, url is changed that.

https://www.google.co.kr/search?q=yen&num=100&hl=en&tbm=nws&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:4/20/2014,cd_max:1/14/2015

>
https://www.google.co.kr/search?q=yen&num=100&hl=en&tbm=nws&gbv=1&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:4/20/2014,cd_max:1/14/2015

I think that *gbv=1* works to ignore search periods. But I can't find why changed this link.

Third,

```
library(rvest)
headlines = read_html("https://www.google.co.kr/search?q=yen&num=100&hl=en&tbm=nws&output=rss&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:4/20/2014,cd_max:1/14/2015") %>%
html_nodes(".r") %>% 
html_text()
```

It has same problem about *gbv=1*.

I found the option *gbv=1*:without JAVA,
*gbv=2*: with JAVA.

I want to know solution any method.